# jquery tmpl grouping function with support for multiple groups

Tags: jquery, grouping, jquery-templates

Couldnt find any example on grouping using jquery tmpl() so thought id post what I came up with (that works) in case anyone else was trying to do it.

Comment: You'd better post the question in the first post, then post an answer and accept it. The documentation does already show plenty of examples: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

Comment: @Rob: Examples, yes, but none which shows grouping. Run the example and you'll see what i mean. btw, i cant accept my own answers

Comment: I can mark yours as the answer though :)

Comment: Improve your title and question, so that (Google) users can find the right answer faster. I'm currently developing a tmpl grouping function with support for multiple groups *hint*.

Comment: any progress? Been almost an hour :) Eager to see what you've got.

Comment: Just finished. I had to make sure that my code was readable and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [JQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) for the basic usage of templates.

I've written an extension to this function, which allows multiple categories to be grouped.
Usage:

`$(`*JQuery template*`).tmpl_sort(`*data*`,`[*options*`,`] *array of groups*`)`
  •   For *JQuery template*, *data* and *options*, see the [tmpl API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/).
  •   *array of groups* should be an array consisting of strings which identify the groups.

Code:

```
 (function($){
     $.fn.tmpl_sort = function(data, options_or_groups, array_groups){
         return $.tmpl_sort(this, data, options_or_groups, array_groups);
     }
     $.tmpl_sort = function(template, data, options_or_groups, array_groups){
         if(typeof array_groups == "undefined"){
             array_groups = options_or_groups;
             options_or_groups = void 0;
         }
         array_groups = typeof array_groups == "string" || typeof array_groups == "number" ? [array_groups] : array_groups;
         if(!(array_groups instanceof Array)) throw new TypeError("$.fn.tmpl_sort: second argument has to be a string or array");
         var groups = {};
         for(var i=0; i<array_groups.length; i++){
             (function(groupname){
                 var last;
                 groups[groupname] = function(group){
                     /* === is a strict comparison operator */
                     return last === (last=group);
                 }
             })(array_groups[i]);
         }
         return template.tmpl(data, groups, options_or_groups)
     }
  })(jQuery);
```

**Example at http://jsfiddle.net/gBTzU/**

```
var Leagues = [
     { League: 1, Group: "A", Team: "France" },
     { League: 1, Group: "A", Team: "China" },
     { League: 1, Group: "B", Team: "Brazil" },
     { League: 2, Group: "A", Team: "England" },
     { League: 2, Group: "A", Team: "Scotland" },
     { League: 2, Group: "B", Team: "India" }
 ];
 $("#itemtemplate").tmpl_sort(Leagues, ["sameleague", "samegroup"]).appendTo("#lvList");
```

Comment: This function may look larger than your previous one, but that's because I've included checks and error messages for portability. This code can be added to the JS file, and included in any web page.

Comment: If you don't understand a part of the code, feel free to request an explanation.

Comment: hahaha when i first looked at it i was like wtf! I think I need more time with jQuery to understand whats going on there :)

Comment: View the source of JQuery. I'm sure that most of the users of JQuery won't use less characters (JQUery + actual code). JQuery has grown big because of the ease of implementing, and the several plugins which result in human-readable scripts.

Comment: This only seems to work if the data is sorted ahead of time.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/Bdk6d/

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #lvList { float:left; }
        .league { background-color: #E8F6FF; }
        .group { background-color: #FEEAEB; margin-left: 10px; }
        .team { margin-left: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="itemtemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
        {{if !$item.sameasbefore("League") }}
            <div class="league">League: ${League}</div>
        {{/if}}
        {{if !$item.sameasbefore("Group") }}
            <div class="group">Group: ${Group}</div>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="team">${Team}</div>
    </script>

    <div id="lvList"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Leagues = [
            { League: 1, Group: "A", Team: "France" },
            { League: 1, Group: "A", Team: "China" },
            { League: 1, Group: "B", Team: "Brazil" },
            { League: 2, Group: "A", Team: "England" },
            { League: 2, Group: "A", Team: "Scotland" },
            { League: 2, Group: "B", Team: "India" }
        ];

    var grouping = [];
    $("#itemtemplate").tmpl(Leagues, {
        sameasbefore: function (field) {
            var same = false;
            if (grouping[field] === this.data[field])
                same = true;
            grouping[field] = this.data[field];
            return same;
        }
    }).appendTo("#lvList");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could write a more efficient function, which also works with multiple groups. Want me to try and post it?

Comment: Fantastic Rob. Much appreciated. Im not actually using it (yet), just saturday night playing :).  The dataset must not change

Comment: @Rob: Modified my answer so you can use the same routine for multiple grouping.. i think its a bit simpler solution than yours, although appreciated the effort.

Comment: It's not portable. The point of using JQuery is code-readability and simplicity (certainly not performance). Compare the bottom of my answer (implementation of the code) to your code. A novice can easily understand how to use `tmpl_sort`, but they won't be able to implement the logic as described in your answer.

Comment: that is true :) although im sure a quick example would set them straight :p